# Создание корректного запроса для поиска в SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть база данных SQLite куда импортирована база адресов - КЛАДР. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу сделать общий запрос для поиска по названию города/населённого пункта. Не очень понимаю как это можно реализовать по данной таблице. Пишу приложение на C# для поиска по этой базе, пока только додумался как сделать поиск по региону.

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT NAME, SOCR FROM KLADR WHERE substr(CODE, 3, 11) = '00000000000' AND (NAME LIKE '%{0}%' OR SOCR LIKE '%{0}%');
```

Только вот я ищу по региону, а мне необходимо чтобы возвращал таблицу совпадений по населенному пункту, как на этой картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура CODE:

СС РРР ГГГ ППП УУУУ АА, где

СС - код субъекта РФ (региона)
РРР - код района
ГГГ - код города
ППП - код населенного пункта
УУУУ - код улицы (отсутствует у населенных пунктов)
АА - признак актуальности

Сама КЛАДР-база в формате SQLite - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mgw5TlJ_4pQs-X6m0z6ZjtCZIbdQUZa-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример запроса и результат.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, обновил

Comment: Если убрать из запроса `substr(CODE, 3, 11) = '00000000000' AND` работает?

Comment: работает, но он не формирует полный адрес

Comment: т.е не формирует Нижегородская обл., Городецкий р-н, г Заволжье на выходе

Comment: он находит только заволжье

Comment: Вам в selecte надо получить ещё поле `CODE`. Разобрать его на части (это не SQL код будет). И по этим частям отдельными SQL запросами извлечь область, район и т.п. Может быть это можно сделать и одним запросом. В любом случае нужны структуры других справочников, которые отобразят код области в имя область, код района в имя района и т.п.

Comment: да это я понимаю, написал поэтому, может кто поможет логику реализовать

Comment: Тогда покажите те, другие справочники, без них запрос не составят. Для примера добавьте ещё только одну таблицу с областями. Я распишу `join` по двум таблицам, чтобы вы получили пункт и область.

Comment: так это таблица и с областями и с населёнными пунктами, там все по коду читается, расшифровка которого выше

Comment: Зашарьте ваш sqlite файл.

Comment: сейчас, насколько я знаю там ещё индексы расставить надо для корректной и быстрой работы поиска, зашарю в вопрос